# WebGL with Kinetic?

Tags: javascript, webgl, kineticjs

I noticed when learning WebGL that it uses a canvas element to render. That being said, could I potentially use something like Kinetic js if Im doing simple shapes and tweens on a WebGL canvas?

Answer (score 0):

While you could* have a (for instance) THREE.JS background going on, and have another DIV on top of that with Kinetic shapes... they are not on the same canvas at the same time - but you could definitely have both libraries working on the same screen at the same time. I suppose.

Although you can tween Three.js shapes... and have click effects on those --- and you can tween Kinetic shapes... and have click effects on those ---

so what the difference in the two libraries really is... is where is your source artwork coming from.

If you are building art in a 3D program such as (for instance) Blender, then exporting the art to Three.js... then animating/tweening/making it interactive...  that's what three.js is best at.

If you are building art in Adobe Illustrator (for instance) or some other vector art program, and then want to export it to Kinetic, and add tweening and interaction... that's what Kinetic is best at.

So back to your original question -- yes. But why. I suppose if you wanted a kinetic effect on top of a three.js effect you would be able to do it with some effort.